# Unable to detect manual URL change in address bar for SPA in jQuery

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, url-routing, fetch-api, html5-history

I'm trying to build a search engine UI as a **single page application** using **jQuery**.

I'm using **fetch API** for loading content and **History API** for navigation.

I want non-hashed urls.
I'm manually adding url params on search
which look this way

```
/?query=myQuery
```

Lets say the URL was currently /?q=firstQuery and the user changes it to /?q=secondQuery by himself in address bar.

**I want to be able to detect the URL change and get the query value from params and fetch the results.**

**I've tried using**

1. popState event listeners - only detect back and forward button changes
2. timeOut function to detect url changes - didn't detect the manual entries

I can see that the browser loads when URL is manually entered and the browser console gets cleared as well.

Is there a way to detect that change? - $(document).ready() , window.on('load') , beforeunload event listeners didn't work. There is only one index.html file that is loaded and the content is being manipulated in it.

I want it to be like [qwant.com](qwant.com) - pl suggest other methods to implement its behaviour in jQuery

Comment: You could use a cookie.

Comment: @Grumpy can you elaborate please? 
More context
Lets say the URL was currently /?q=firstQuery and the user changes it to /?q=secondQuery by himself in address bar, how do i detect that with a cookie?

Comment: Set the cookie at first enter with the url params, every time the page is reloaded, compare it with the cookie

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event#usage_notes) event to look for the manual changes to the URL, but it is not a very reliable method as laid out in the MDN document.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  const currentUrl = location.pathname;
  if (currentUrl !== '/') {
    loadPage(currentUrl);
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?';
  }
}
```

You're better off using a router library written by someone else, which will handle all the routing problems by itself.